# How many 1's are there in selected column/row in Informatica?

Tags: count, expression, informatica

I am very new to Informatica. Now I would like to **Count** how many 1's are there in selected row in Informatica, which we could do easily in excel using COUNTIF formula.

**For example**, column1 - a,b,c,d ; column2 - 1,2,1,4 ; column3 - 1,1,3,5

How to write expression in Informatica to calculate how many 1's are there in each row (a,b,c,d)?

Answer (score 2):

occurrence of any string can be calculated like this -

```
length(column1 ) - length(replacechr(column1,'1',''))
```

Take the total length of string and then minus length of everything else in the string.
Use an exp transformation and calculate how many 1 exist in column column1 ,column2,column3...